How can I argue for most productive hours with my PhD supervisor?
For context, I'm a second year PhD student (Marine Ecology) in the UK with own funding (from research council), my lab consists of me, my PI and some last-year undergrads.
My PI is a 9-5 Nazi towards their students and I had been coming in for 9-5 for most of my first and second years. Now I'm doing experiments with an organism which needs to be collected at a specific developmental stage within a 2-3 hour window and sometimes I have to collect them during the weekends and/or at ungodly hours so I shift my working day to afternoon/evening/night hours. My PI gets livid about me not being seen in the mornings, when I explain they say "Yes but still I feel like there's a problem you're not telling me about" as if I working nights and then mornings after that meant to be normal.
They argue that what I do can be done within 9-5 (which is impossible, I have a feeling they say that because they never did this experiment themselves) so talking to them feels like talking to a wall. Generally, they are the kind of person who only hears what they want to hear and then look surprised when stuff happens and pretends no one told them when I would have done several times.
In the past two months they told me twice that they're happy with my volume of work, this gave me confidence to argue that my working hours are productive when I choose them myself. Later they argued that actually I'm not up to speed just because I'm not always seen in the office, and that they were just unclear with me before. I happen to keep voice recordings of our meetings (for my own use and without their knowledge) and my memory of what they said is correct.
I feel that the schedule they're forcing on me is killing my ability to do my best in this project, firstly due to inability to concentrate when I'm chronically underslept and secondly due to anxiety from this pressure which I see as completely unnecessary. Any debate between me and my PI is difficult because they don't listen and believe they're always right without giving an explanation.
Is this something I can discuss with my tutor and how can my tutor fix it? How can I protect myself from my PI if they get vindictive?
Edited to update: a week later I casually mentioned how much data I acquired and they were shocked and in disbelief. So it seems that they had a go at me for not doing enough before they actually found out how much work I had done over the past month, I guess because they did not always see me in the lab. And I did tell them I had to work evenings and weekends when I'm not around, I don't know why that wasn't clear to them.
Also edited to remove details that could make me identifiable.

How experienced is your PI? Are they new at this? Also, how critical is this research to their own career?

@Buffy From what the previous student had told me, my PI started their lab about 10 years ago, they have only had four PhD students before me. In the past five years they only published one paper and not a single grant that I've heard of. I'm not sure how critical this research is to them, I always thought they don't seem to care much about their career.

Do you have documentation on your medical condition (insomnia)? And have you spoken to your ombudsperson about this?

@coffee_into_plots I do but it was in my home country (outside of EU) so I guess I'd need to have that translated or get diagnosed again which is a hassle and dealing with NHS (registering with GP which I haven't done yet, queues, etc) waste so much time during the day that I fear my PI will get mad at my absence again. I've never heard of PhD ombudspeople, is that a thing in the UK? There doesn't seem to be one here.

I missed the UK tag, unfortunately. But there should be some sort of person to mediate student-supervisor conflicts, or have an eye on student wellbeing, right? Otherwise having some medical diagnosis could be an argument to get accommodations, but I don't know enough about the UK to answer this properly.

@coffee_into_plots I think that would be one of my thesis committee members who was assigned as my "tutor" to whom apparently I can talk about my relationship with my PI if I need to. However I heard another academic say that the tutors tend to back their colleagues against the students so I don't know if it's worth speaking to my tutor.  Thank you for sharing your thoughts!

I am just finishing my PhD and had the same problem, also in the UK. I was working in a computational field and despite that I was required to be 9 to 5 in the office, even worse: I could not be late, and would receive an email if I was not in the office at 9:10 or 16:50.
I went the official route about discussing work arrangement first with the designated person, which happened to be a close colleague of my supervisor, it did not work out and this person mostly backed up my supervisor. I then went to the head of department and got what I wanted.
My supervisor did not like it and as a consequence my PhD is probably way weaker than it could have been (I am assuming). I realized our collaborators also changed attitude towards me, which might be a consequence (also assuming).
I am fine with it since in my opinion I did the right thing (there were other, more serious problems), but academia will look down on you, and despite universities marketing themselves as progressive employers, chances are that you will perform badly in academia if you don't have support from your advisor.
In my case talking with my supervisor did not work out, they were 100% committed to the 9 to 5. If you are fine with the potential consequences I described above, then go and fight - throughout history most labor rights were earned through some form of struggle. If you feel your career advancement is more important, then you'll have to accept the situation.

To me it sounds unreasonable to require you in the lab at 9am the following morning if you have been working into the night on a time course. For me that would be an automatic day off in lieu the next day.
That said, I have some sympathy for your supervisor's position also. Remember, it is your supervisors job not to ensure that you personally are at most productive, but that the team as a whole is as productive as possible. If you have undergraduates on the team, they probably benefit from having you present at the same time as them.
My line for my people is that as a baseline you should be working at least 40 hours a week, and that those 40 hours should include being in the office for some pre-agreed "core" hours most weeks - by default 10-4, four days out of Monday to Friday. This allows some flexibility, while ensuring their is some time for casual support and chit-chat (that is surprisingly beneficial to more junior members), building a esprit de-corps. I am always open to specific requests for people with particular needs - health needs, caring responsibilities etc., but discussions take place against the assumption that the goal is to balance the needs of the lab against the needs of the individual, not just to always do only what is best for the individual.
Have you tried asking your supervisor why he thinks 9-5 is so important, and seeing if you can come up with an alternative arrangement that takes the middle ground between his goals and yours?
Of course some people are just not reasonable people. In that case there is not much you can do other than the official complaint route, but I doubt you'll get far with that (other than time off in lieu of late nights), or if you have specific needs - your insomnia might get you somewhere here (its unlikely that you'll need to be rediagnosed). If you want to go the official route, start with your tutor. If that doesn't work go to the department/school PGR director, university student services, or your student's union.

If OP is really dependent on an organism that has "random" hours, this must be factored in into the working arrangements. I used to have a phase with 24-hour day/night shifts for measurements, and practically no plannable private life during this time, as you would measure whenever the apparatus worked. Nobody would have expected me to come in the day after. Frankly, I do not see any negotiation leeway here. The alternative is to measure if the organism is alive/developing in the 9-5 window and not doing that otherwise, "as per instruction".

@CaptainEmacs I noted at the beginning that days during or after an experiment with long or unpredictable hours should of course be excluded from any required schedule.

You did, but then talked about "sympathy for the supervisor". Of course, that's legit, but I always felt I got the best result by being more flexible, especially when it does not really matter. Obviously, that does not apply to meetings or logistics etc. But this idea of presenteeism never convinced me. I give my group very substantial leeway - the result is that they work twice as hard and go out of their way to get results or do something when I am asking them to do it. Anyway, if it works for you... The concept of core hours remains as mysterious to me as that of regular nothingmeetings.
